# Script works fine until I use variable for the server name

Tags: powershell

This script works perfectly until I put in `$Server` as the computer name instead of the actual computer name.  Please advise.  The error I get is `ERROR: Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "URI formats are not supported."`

```powershell
$Servers = Get-Content -Path C:\temp\servers.txt

foreach ($Server in $Servers)
{
  $web = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
  $web.DownloadFile("http://$server:1055/sinfo?gr=1","c:\temp\Test.xml")

  [xml] $xdoc = Get-Content c:\Temp\test.xml
  $properties = @{
    Serialnumber = $xdoc.sinfo.systeminfo.bios.SerialNumber;
           Model = $xdoc.sinfo.systeminfo.sys.Model;
    Manufacturer = $xdoc.sinfo.systeminfo.sys.Manufacturer;
    ComputerName = $xdoc.sinfo.systeminfo.sys.Name;
          Domain = $xdoc.sinfo.systeminfo.sys.Domain;
  }
}

$obj = new-object psobject -property $properties 
$obj | Select-Object model, manufacturer, ComputerName, domain, SerialNumber | export-csv c:\temp\results.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

Comment: Is there any whitespace in those lines? Perhaps use `$($server.Trim())` in place of just `$server`. Have you looked at the output of the `"http://$server:1055/sinfo?gr=1"` on its own and not part of `DownloadFile`?

Comment: also if you do it like that the properties variable will be overwritten everytime the loop runs so $obj will only contain the result for the last server

Comment: @Matt I have looked at the file and it is in xml format.  I tried the trim and still getting the "URI formats are not supported" as soon as I put in the $server variable

Comment: @Paul It looks like it is appending to the csv file correctly.

Comment: @Paul You were right.  It is overwriting the records :(  Where do I put it that it will keep adding to the csv file as it goes through the server list?

Comment: i would suggest you collect them in an array

Comment: @Paul,  can you please share an example of what you mean about collecting them in them in an array?

Comment: you create an array `$array=@()` then add the object inside the for loop `$array += new-object psobject -property $properties `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colon is the [scope operator](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx) in PowerShell.  Your script is looking for a variable `$server:1055`, meaning it's looking for `$1055` in the scope or namespace of `server`.

Try:

```
"http://$server`:1055/sinfo?gr=1"
```

Or:

```
"http://$($server):1055/sinfo?gr=1"
```

Or:

```
"http://${server}:1055/sinfo?gr=1"
```

Comment: That was it @BaconBits !  This worked liked a charm. "http://$server`:1055/sinfo?gr=1"